# How to use IF in Switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement, average

How to apply if condition in Switch statement, I want to calculate Average: however I have tried for best to solve the issue but still getting no output from Switch statement. 
I am beginner to the C++,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declaration of variables.
    int sub1,sub2,sub3, sub4,sub5,total,avg;

    //accepting marks from user in each subject
    cout << " Enter Programming in C++ Marks: " << endl;
    cin >> sub1;
    cout << " Enter Software Engineering Marks : " << endl;
    cin >> sub2;
    cout << " Enter Personal Communication Marks : " << endl;
    cin >> sub3;
    cout << " Enter Database Application Marks: " << endl;
    cin >> sub4;
    cout << " Enter Computer Concept Marks: " << endl;
    cin >> sub5;

    //calculatin sum of marks obtained in each subject
    total = (sub1 + sub2 + sub3 + sub4 + sub5);

    //calculating the average marks
    avg = total / 5;

    // starting of if condition for finding out grades of total subjects.

    switch (avg){
      case 1:{
        if ((avg >= 80) && (avg <= 100))
        {
            cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
            cout << "You Grade is A+ " << endl;
        }
        break; 
      }
      case 2:{
        if ((avg >= 70) && (avg <= 79))
        {
            cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
            cout << " Your grade is A " << endl;
        }    
        break;
      } 
      case 3:{
        if ((avg >= 60) && (avg <= 69))
        { 
            cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
            cout << " Your Grade is B+  " << endl;
        }   
        break;  
      }
      case 4:{
        if ((avg >= 50) && (avg <= 59))
        {
            cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
            cout << " Your Grade is C+ " << endl;
        }
        break;
      }
      case 5: {
        if ((avg >= 40) && (avg <= 49))
        {
            cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
            cout << " Your Grade is  C- ! " << endl;
        }
        break;    
      }
      case 6: {
        if ((avg >= 30) && (avg <= 39))
        {
            cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
            cout << " Your Grade is  D ! " << endl;
        }
        break; 
      }

      default:{ 
        if ((avg >= 100) && (avg <= 29))
        {
            cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
            cout << " Your Grade is  F, So you are Fail in the class ! " << endl;
            break;
        }
      }
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I guess that you have missunderstood the use of switch case. Remove the switch case and you will get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks For your Valuable Reply. I know the code is incorrectly Typed but I want to clear I just switch statement only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The switch statement is used to execute one block of code dependent on a particular value. In a sense, the switch statement can be thought of as a form of an if statement: the code

```
switch (avg) {
   case 1 : { /* code block 1 */ } break;
   case 2 : { /* code block 2 */ } break;
   default : { /* code block default */ } break;
}
```

can be read as

```
if (1 == avg) { /* code block 1 */ }
else if (2 == avg) { /* code block 2 */ }
else { /*code block default */ }
```

Your switch statement can be read as

```
if (1 == avg) 
{
   if ((avg >= 80) && (avg <= 100))
   {
      cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
      cout <<  "You Grade is A+ " << endl;
   }
} else if...
```

and there's no way avg can == 1 and be greater than 80 and less than 100, which is why you don't get any output.

In C++, the switch statement doesn't lend itself well to testing for ranges; I'd just use an if statement:

```
if ( (avg<=100) && (avg >=80))
{
   // you get an A
} else if ...
```

But, if you really really need to use a switch, there are a few ways to go about it:

```
switch (avg) {
   case 100:
   case 99:
   case 98:
   ...
   case 80 : { /* you get an A+ */ break; }
   case 79 :
   case 78 : 
   ...
   case 70 : { /* you get a A */ break: }
etc.
```

This is ugly, but it *is* a switch statement.  A cleaner way to use the switch statement could be to "force" avg to a discrete value, instead of a range.

```
int percentile = avg / 10;  // integer division.
```

Now range is going to be between 0 and 10, assuming avg is between 0 and 100. This will make for a slightly cleaner switch:

```
switch (percentile) { 
   case 10 :
   case 9:
   case 8: /* You get an A+ */ break;
   case 7: /* You get an A */ break;
   case 6: /* You get a B+ */ break;

etc.
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Dear Brismith, I am really confused about my solution in I already done this in if & else if but I want to get the same output by using switch statement. Kindly Make as simple and easier in switch. Regards

Comment: Yes Obviously. I am thankful for your efforts.  will you please tell me how to accept the anser

Comment: @BinYousif Just click the checkmark outline; it'll turn green

Answer (score 7):

Well, `switch` compares the `case`s with the variable you gave it. So for `case 1` it tries comparing `avg` to `1` and *after* that it would go on with your `if` statement, which, of course, would never apply.

I'm not really sure what you're trying there; from all I can see you're better off with a nested `if`:

```
if ((avg >= 80) && (avg <= 100))
{
  cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
  cout << "You Grade is A+ " << endl;
} else if ((avg >= 70) && (avg <= 79))
{
  cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
  cout << " Your grade is A " << endl;
} else if ((avg >= 60) && (avg <= 69))
{ 
  cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
  cout << " Your Grade is B+  " << endl;
} ...
```

But even that can be handled more elegantly, depending on your skills. For example, you can divide the average by 10 and use `switch` on that, exploiting the fact that integer division truncates, collapsing everything between `50` and `59` into the same bucket `5`:

```
switch (avg / 10) {
  case 10:
  case 9:
  case 8:
    cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
    cout << "You Grade is A+ " << endl;
    break;
  case 7:
    cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
    cout << "You Grade is A " << endl;
  ...
}
```

Also you'll notice that you print  »*Your average is: ...*« every time, so you can move that line *before* the conditions:

```
cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
switch (avg / 10) {
  ...
}
```

Finally, since you have a quite small list of possible outcomes, you can collect them in an array and simply reference the appropriate array element, without even needing an `if`/`else if` or `switch`:

```
char[][] grades = {
  "F", "F", "F", "D", "C-", "C+", "B+", "A", "A+", "A+", "A+"
};
char[] grade;
if (avg > 100)
  grade = "F";
else
  grade = grades[max(0, avg / 10)];

cout << " Your average is " << avg << endl;
cout << " Your grade is " << grade << endl;
```

Comment: Note: All code untested and my C/C++ is rusty right now. But you should get the general idea. Corrections welcome :)

Comment: My Dear. thanks for your time and valueable reply with your reply (perfect Reply) I solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The Code is always going in your default statment , as your switch statment will not be getting any input as provided in case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can you please define it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You are using switch a little wrong, it's not the `if` problem. This:

```
switch (avg){
    case 1:{
        if ((avg >= 80) && (avg <= 100))
        {
            cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
            cout << "You Grade is A+ " << endl;
        }
        break;
```

means the same as

```
if( avg == 1 )
{
    if ((avg >= 80) && (avg <= 100))
    {
        cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
        cout << "You Grade is A+ " << endl;
    }
}
```

So obviously the condition will never be met. For your particular case, you can just remove the switch and leave just the `if`s.

Comment: Brother, I understand now I removed the conditions at this case 6:  (avg >= 30) && (avg <= 39);
cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
cout << " Your Grade is  D ! " << endl;
break; 
{
default:  (avg <= 29);
cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
cout << " Your Grade is  F, So you are Fail in the class ! " << endl;
break;
{

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Switch- case` and you will get your desired output, as in this case it is going in default always.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
Switch(avg)

{
   case 1:
   break;
}
```

it is same as saying `if(avg == 1)`. So remove your switch case and handle it like this

```
if ((avg >= 80) && (avg <= 100))
//do this
else if ((avg >= 70) && (avg <= 79))
//do that
```

Comment: How can I do it in switch. does I have to create all the cases. e.g from 1. to 100..

Answer (score 0):

The case situations like 1, 2, 3 are recognized as the value of avg, by the switch statement.

You can only use the switch() control with certain values, NOT intervals. I recommend you to use else if{} structure in this case.

Or u can implement 1 statement in multiple cases (but wont be readable).

```
switch(avg){
   case 80: case 81: case 82:   //do this until 100

      cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
      cout << "You Grade is A+ " << endl;
      break;
}
```

And you dont need to use scopes (curly brackets) for each case.

Comment: Brother Let me try this. I hope it will be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

The best and probably the easiest thing to do is get rid of the switch statement and use "if" and "elseif".

Answer (score -1):

switch (avg){

```
        case 80 ... 100:

        cout << " Your Average is: " << avg << endl;
        cout << "You Grade is A+ " << endl;

    break;
  }
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).